# CakeEmail Function, Issues & Problems

Tags: email, cakephp

This is starting to (might have already) drive me mad! There does not seem to be a lot of help about how to use the inbuilt CakePHP CakeEmail.

I have found a number of posts on this site, as well as a you tube vid which is was helpful but the guy explaining was not specking in English so was a litle hard to follow him at times.

I have a view file with a basic form inside it, which ponits to my send() function inside my controller but I get nothing but errors.

Here is my current code:

UPDATE ::

The errors I am getting are,

```
     Undefined index: to [APP/Controller/ContactController.php, line 26]
```

And

```
     Error: Call to a member function subject() on a non-object 
     File: /var/www/app/Controller/ContactController.php    
     Line: 27
```

Which I just don't understand, I have called the CakeEmail right? I have copied the code right but these are the errors I get each time I submit the from.

Thanks Glenn.

Another Update ::

I have removed the code from before, I have got it to work (sort of)

//New Contact.cpt

```
echo $this->Form->create(array('controller' => 'contact', 'url' => '/contact/send') );
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.to');
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.subject');
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.message', array('type' => 'textarea') );
echo $this->Form->submit('Email Us', array('class' => 'Button'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

//New Controller

```
public function send() {

    if ( !empty($this->request->data) ) {
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config('default');
        $email->from(array('contact@me.com' => 'ME'))
              ->to('contact@me.com')
              ->subject($this->request->data['ContactForm']['subject']);
        if ( $email->send($this->request->data['ContactForm']['message']) ) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Email Sent...'), 'default', array('class' => 'success') );
        }

    }
    $this->render('/Contact/Contact');

} //End of function send
```

But Now I want to change the layout, my form will will be

//This is what I want ->

```
echo $this->Form->create(array('controller' => 'contact', 'url' => '/contact/send') );
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.name');
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.email');
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.phone');
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.subject');
echo $this->Form->input('ContactForm.message', array('type' => 'textarea') );
echo $this->Form->submit('Email Us', array('class' => 'Button'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

I need to take name, email and phone number but when I add then to the $email in my controller all i get is this error

```
  error: Call to undefined method CakeEmail::name()
```

//Controller Code Section That I changed

```
        $email->from(array('contact@me.com' => 'Me'))
              ->to('contact@me.com')
              ->name($this->request->data['ContactForm']['name']) <-That is the line I added!
              ->subject($this->request->data['ContactForm']['subject']);
```

If this is not the right way, which I am guesting its not, then how do I change the email layout to included the list of items I want. I have looked over (many times) the CakeEmail document but its not very clear and just does not give any working code of how to change from the default.

Thanks Glenn

Comment: Although you included a lot of code, you did not describe what exactly isn't working. Also did you try to manually send the e-mail, using 'fixed' strings instead of form-data? (to narrow down the cause of the problem)

Comment: I am not sure how to set fixed data with out getting more bloody errors, but your right I did not say what the errors are, see update

Answer (score 1):

You have a few simple errors in your code.

This is wrong

```
->to($this->request->data['to'])
```

`debug($this->request->data)` to see the structure of the array

You have `Undefined index: to [APP/Controller/ContactController.php, line 26]` as an error but I do not see anything referencing index in your code. Either you are making this up or not pasted the correct code. I suspect its probably the same problem as the `$this->request->data` issue I mentioned.